# MySQL join from two tables with one condition

Tags: php, mysql, join

I can't figure out join.. 
need to select all rows from one table where a column equals something in another table..

like this:

```
SELECT ALL FROM someTable 
WHERE COLUMN someColumn = '123' (IN A DIFFERENT TABLE)
```

something like that..
and the IDs need to match of course..

Comment: Try Left join in mysql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SomeTable S
    JOIN SomeOtherTable S2 
        ON S.SomeKey = S2.SomeKey
WHERE S.SomeColumn = '123'
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

I wasn't completely clear of your question, so you may not need the `WHERE` clause if that represented your `JOIN` criteria.

Comment: Maybe there might be `SELECT S.* ...`

Comment: @CORRUPT -- good addition.  Hoping just to help poster understand how to use JOINs.

Comment: This worked beautifully and the visual explanation of SQL Joins looks like a good read. Thanks  =]

Comment: @bushdiver -- great to hear, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
A bit error in my question, let me clarify
tblplace
id  place
1  London
2  Paris
3  New York

tbltraveller
tr_id  tr_name    id
1       John      3
2       Jackson   2
3       Susanna   1
4       Jimmy     3
5       Lucy      2
```

The problem is missing some data for New York:

```
Paris         Jackson Lucy
New York
```

My code(guess there is an error in the while loop):

```
<?php
require_once("connMysql1.php");
$qry = "SELECT * FROM tblPlace WHERE tblPlace.id > 1 ORDER BY tblPlace.id";
$result = mysqli_query($db_link, $qry);
$qry1 = "SELECT tblPlace.id, tblPlace.Place, tbltraveller.tr_id, 
tbltraveller.tr_name, tbltraveller.id FROM tblPlace INNER JOIN tbltraveller ON 
tblPlace.id = tbltraveller.id WHERE tblPlace.id > 1 ORDER BY tbltraveller.id";
$result1 = mysqli_query($db_link, $qry1);
$no_of_row1 = mysqli_num_rows($result1);
$no_of_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo "<table border=1 cellpadding=10>";
if ($no_of_row >0){
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo $row['place']."<br>";
echo "</td>"."&nbsp;";
echo "<td>";
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
if($row1['id'] == $row['id']){
echo $row1['tr_name']."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
}
}
echo "</td>";
"</tr>";
}
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

`

Comment: As an example, the where clause is to show the persons travel to Paris and New York. The problem is: I cannot show persons(John, Jimmy) travel to New York. The while ($row1 = mysqli......) loop only display persons to Paris but not persons to New York.